# javascript focus on textbox on failed validation working differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

I am validating a textbox and if validation fails focus should be on the same textbox. 
I searched on internet but not found any appropriate answer for this.

When I open my asp page in firefox the focus goes on to another control after alert message is closed and in chrome the alert message can not be closed, it reappears everytime I click the ok button or close button of the alert window.

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputAge" class="col-md-2 control-label" id="lblAge">Age</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="inputAge" placeholder="35 or 25D or 5M"  runat="server" required="required" maxlength="3" onblur="return ValidateAge()" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateAge() {
            var str = document.getElementById("inputAge").value;
            var number_regex = /^[1-9]\d*$/;

            if (str.slice(-1) === 'm') {
                var number_part = str.slice(0, -1);

                if (!number_regex.test(number_part)) {
                    alert("invalid age1");
                    document.getElementById("inputAge").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (number_part > 12) {
                    alert("invalid age2");
                    document.getElementById("inputAge").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

How can I set focus to the same textbox if the validation fails?

Comment: can you change onblur to onchange if that works? or please debug from  the browser if you find why its coming error or is it going to server side and losing focus?

Answer (score 0):

This issue depends on `document.getElementById("inputAge").focus()` javascript statement, that triggers another `blur` event. So you need to implement a sort of `state` handling that helps you to avoid the execution of `ValidateAge()` due to this side effect.

Try this implementation as well:

```
        var cancelBlurEvent = false;
        function ValidateAge() {

            if(cancelBlurEvent === true){
              return cancelBlurEvent = false;
            } 

            var str = document.getElementById("inputAge").value;
            var number_regex = /^[1-9]\d*$/;
            if (str.slice(-1) === 'm') {
                var number_part = str.slice(0, -1);

                if (!number_regex.test(number_part)) {
                    alert("invalid age1");
                    cancelBlurEvent = true //it is important to change cancelBlurEvent value before next statement
                    document.getElementById("inputAge").focus();
                    return cancelBlurEvent;
                }
                else if (number_part > 12) {
                    alert("invalid age2");
                    cancelBlurEvent = true
                    document.getElementById("inputAge").focus();
                    return cancelBlurEvent;
                }
                else {
                    return cancelBlurEvent = false;
                }
            }
        }
```